# Run a node.js file on boot on a raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I want to launch a node js server on the boot of my raspberry pi.
The moment the server is running, chromium browser should start up and show the webpage.
At this moment, I've only managed to let the chromium browser start up but the response is a localhost: connection refused.

I've tried two ways but it didn't workout

Option 1:
using an external shell file:

The boot command:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
@/home/pi/autostart.sh
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --start-maximized http://localhost:3000/
```

The shell file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Documents/.../
node connect.js
```

Option 2: using inline command in the bootfile:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
@node /home/pi/.../connect.js
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --start-maximized http://localhost:3000/
```

Anyone who knows a solution?

Comment: If it's a long running service, you probably should create `systemd` service ... There are tons of tutorials out there how to create one, also specifically doing it on a raspi

Comment: I got a working service script that executes my demand of running the server. How can I integrate it in my boot file?

Comment: for instance ... https://simonprickett.dev/writing-a-systemd-service-in-node-js-pi/